# System.ArgumentException: Data Source cannot be empty

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am not a programer, I just have a passion for this. I am doing a project which can facilitate my work, but I am facing the error described when connecting to the DB. Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string dbcon = "@Data Source= KMS.db;Version=3;";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection sqlcon = new SQLiteConnection(dbcon);
        if ((textusername.Text == "") && (textpassword.Text == "") || (textusername.Text == "") || (textpassword.Text == ""))
        {
            EmptyErrorLabel.Visible = true;
            EmptyErrorLabel.Text = "Username and / or password are empty!";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username = '" + textusername.Text + "' AND Password = '" + textpassword.Text + "'";
                SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(query, sqlcon);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SQLiteDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                int i = 0;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    i++;
                }
                if(i == 1)
                {
                    KMS_MainMenu MainMenu = new KMS_MainMenu();
                    MainMenu.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }

                if(i < 1)
                {
                    EmptyErrorLabel.Visible = true;
                    EmptyErrorLabel.Text = "Invalid Username and / or Password";
                    textpassword.Clear();
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error while logging: " + ex);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: remove the '@' in "@Data Source= KMS.db;Version=3;", maybe?

Comment: Your @ is misplaced. If should be outside of your string like that: @"Data Source= KMS.db;Version=3;". More details of what the @ symbol means when used with string: [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#Instantiation)